# Wierd behaviour with autoincrement and where from sqlite-net-pcl

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a login function that take an email and a pw and return the user with that email (emails are unique)

I have a static DB class that handles the access to the db and in this function i retrieve the user that logs

```
public static async Task<User> GetUser(string email, int uid)
        {
            await Init();
            //var user = await db.GetAsyn<User>(id);
            var user = await db.Table<User>().Where(x => x.Email == email).FirstAsync();
          
            List<User> list = await db.Table<User>().ToListAsync();
            var list1 = await db.Table<User>().Where(x => x.id == uid).ToListAsync();

            foreach(var usr in list)
            {
                var name = user.Name;
                var em = user.Email;
                var id1 = user.id;
            }
            return user;
        }
```

I saw 2 problems. If i use Where(x => x.id == uid) it return null even if in my db there are 3 users with id 0 (witch is also the value of uid) idk why. That foreach loop its for debugging.

And the second problem is that in my user model i marked the id property with autoincrement and primary key but it looks like it did not increment the id since i have 3 user with id 0

This is how i difined my id property

```
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int id { get; }
```

This is where I add new Users

```
     public static async Task<int> Add(User user)
        {
            await Init();
            return await db.InsertAsync(user);

        }
```

and from here I call it

```
async Task Register()
        {
            if(!(IsEmailValid && IsNameValid && IsPwValid && IsPwconfValid))
            {
                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Data entered is not valid", "Please check the text in red", "Dismiss");
                return;
            }

            var succed = await DB.Add(User);

            if (succed == 0)
                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Something went wrong with registraition", "Please try again later", "Dismiss");
            else
            {
                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Registraition succeded", "Now you are a member of this awsome app", "WELCOME");
                await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(LoginPage)}");
            }
        }
```

Users is already updated throw bindings

Comment: where is the code where you create and save a user?

Comment: Doesn't `[PrimaryKey]` imply `Unique`? Which would render your DB corrupted?

Comment: @Fildor and how can i check if my DB is corrupted?

Comment: Good question. I would have expected it to throw errors around like crazy, already.

Comment: The property "id" might need to have a setter for AutoIncrement to work.

Answer (score 1):

I use `sqlite-net-pcl version 1.7.335` to save some datas into sqlite database, take a look the following code about create table and save data.

User class:

```
 public class SearchModel
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PERSON { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
}
```

Save User data:

```
public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
{
    public SQLiteConnection conn;
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       conn= GetSQLiteConnection();
    }
    public SQLiteConnection GetSQLiteConnection()
    {
        var fileName = "SearchModel.db";
        var documentPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var path = Path.Combine(documentPath, fileName);

        var connection = new SQLiteConnection(path);
        return connection;
    }

    private void btnadd_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //var data = conn.Table<SearchModel>();
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        {
            SearchModel model = new SearchModel();
            model.PERSON = "person "+ i;
            model.NAME = "cherry "+ i;
            conn.Insert(model);
        }
    }
  
    private void createdb_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn.CreateTable<SearchModel>();
    }
}
```

Inserting data into sqlite database successfully, Id increment.

Comment: One little comment to add. If you have already a table created you first have to drop the table to add a setter

Comment: @Nicoara If you have this table already, migrated table, created table if not exists.